# Python While Loop, Confused on "or" operator

Tags: python, while-loop

Basically I have a while loop that I want to run until either userWins or botWins equal 5. But with this code it will only stop when the variable "userWins" equals 5. I'm newer to python so I don't know if there is a different operator I am supposed to use to make this happen. Thank you for your help.

`while userWins < 5 or botWins < 5:`

Comment: Use `and` instead of `or`

Comment: It will only stop when *both* `userWins` and `bootWins` are `>= 5`. I suspect you want `while userWins < 5 and botWins < 5:`.

Answer (score 1):

So you want to run while both `userWins` and `botWins` are lower than 5.
You should use  `while userWins < 5 and botWins < 5:` that's not a programming problem but a logic problem.

Comment: Man thank you. I have been working on this program for like 5 hours my brain logically thought it had to be or. I am just losing my mind I guess.